Editing Managed Package new Named Credential (not legacy) URL in subscriber org
I'm looking to add a new Named Credential (not legacy) to my managed package.  There's a similar question here, but that's in relation to legacy named credentials.
Looking at the documentation, it says the subscriber can update the URL.
Isn't this a potential security breach?  Or is the doco wrong on this?
If I can't stop the subscriber changing the URL, what alternate approach should I be taking for httpreqeusts from managed package code?
i.e. The subscriber could change the URL to a postman URL and see the headers and and tokens/secrets being passed through.
Doco for reference:

Only Package Developer Can Edit

Label
NamedCredentialType
Legacy Named Credentials only (deprecated and unsupported in future releases)

Endpoint (deprecated)



Both Package Developer and Subscriber Can Edit

CalloutOptions

AllowMergeFieldsInBody
AllowMergeFieldsInHeader
GenerateAuthorizationHeader


NamedCredentialParameters

AllowedManagedPackageNamespaces (only subscriber editable)
Authentication
ClientCertificate (only subscriber editable in 2GP)
HttpHeader
OutboundNetworkConnection
Url


Legacy Named Credentials only (deprecated and unsupported in future releases)

AuthProvider (deprecated)
AuthTokenEndpointUrl (deprecated)
AwsAccessKey, AwsAccessSecret, AwsRegion, and AwsService (all deprecated)
Certificate (deprecated)
JwtAudience, JwtFormulaSubject, JwtIssuer, JwtSigningCertificateId, JwtTextSubject, and JwtValidityPeriodSeconds (all deprecated)
OauthRefreshToken, OauthScope, and OathToken (all deprecated)
OutboundNetworkConnectionId (deprecated)
Password (deprecated)
PrincipalType (deprecated)
Protocol (deprecated)
Username (deprecated)




